# Can anyone explain why my state is getting updated even when i dont set it manually

Tags: reactjs

So I just spent an hour debugging this code and finally got it to work, but I would want to know why this happened in the first place. I have a function that takes a value from my state, operates on it and saves the output in another variable in the state. This is the fuction:

```
getFolderNames = async () => {
    const promises = this.state.rows.map(async item => {
        if (item[".tag"] == "folder" && item.name.length > 20) {
            item.name = await getFolderName(item.name);
            return item;
        } else return item;
    });
    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    this.setState({
        rowsToDisplay: result
    });
};
```

when i run this function, it was updating both the rows and rowsToDisplay to the result variable when i was only calling setState on only one of them.

Changing the function as below solves the issue but I would like to know why.

```
getFolderNames = async () => {
    const promises = this.state.rows.map(async item => {
        if (item[".tag"] == "folder" && item.name.length > 20) {
            let item2 = {
                ...item
            };
            item2.name = await getFolderName(item.name);
            return item2;
        } else return item;
    });
    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    this.setState({
        rowsToDisplay: result
    });
};
```

Comment: Note also that this is directly modifying state. See the [React Docs on how to use state correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how JavaScript handles variables. When you set a variable to an array or object, it doesn't make a new object but rather just references the original array/object.

As such, if you set a variable to equal some object, and then set a property of that variable, the original object will also be updated. Check this snippet for an example.

```js
var foo = {changed: false};
var bar = foo;

bar.changed = true;

console.log("foo", foo.changed)
console.log("bar", bar.changed)
```

You can read more about the subject here: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

I hope this helps you in the future, since I know I also spent many hours banging my head against exactly the sort of cases you described in your original question.